# Find pattern, output new file

Tags: .net, regex, parsing

Im trying to take data thats delimited like:

executable -u admin -p admin -o mylogfile.log -project "ProjectName" -in 20 -data "somedatahere..." -tr "some tracking data"

As a single line in a text, although sometimes there are extra lines ... any way I can a: filter the new lines or b) reoutput a correct version using regex?

All of them must have -tr "" and -data "" etc. (all on a single line)

any easy way to accomplish? via linux or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Use regex `/((\s-data\s+".*?").*(\s-tr\s+".*?")|(\s-tr\s+".*?").*(\s-data\s+".*?"))/`

See and test it [here](http://ideone.com/0FLhY).